# html select menu to submit URL action

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a menu of options like the following:

```
<form>
  <select>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is have each option represent a certain URL action, and the submit input will perform the action of visiting the URL(in a new tab like target="_blank") of the selected option.

```
1 = http://one.example.net
2 = http://two.example.net
3 = http://three.example.net
4 = http://four.example.net
```

I don't know if programming of any kind is required to set the selected option as the action of the submit input.

Comment: You're going to need JavaScript to perform the action. It would probably make sense to set the URLs as the value of your options.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this with PHP? My end game with this is a non-js solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  <script>
    var urls = [
      /* [0] */ 'http://one.example.net',
      /* [1] */ 'http://two.example.net',
      /* [2] */ 'http://three.example.net',
      /* [3] */'http://four.example.net'
    ];
    function goToURL(s){
      // get selected index and subtract one to get the array's index
      var index = parseInt(s.options[s.selectedIndex].value, 10) - 1; 

      // verify a url exists for th eoption, and if so navigate to it
      urls[index] && window.location = urls[index];
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Then add `onchange="goToURL(this);"` to the `<select>` tag.

Quick and dirty example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vfamc/

Comment: Or not. Better to do it unobtrusively

Comment: @mplungjan: "I don't know if programming of any kind" tells me to start basic. No reason to get finite with OP, a short and sweet solution, I'm betting, is fine for his/her usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery...

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    var selectVal = $('select').val();
    var url = '';
    if(selectVal == 1) url = 'http://one.example.net';
    else if(selectVal == 2) url = 'http://two.example.net';
    else if(selectVal == 3) url = 'http://three.example.net';
    else if(selectVal == 4) url = 'http://four.example.net';

    if(url != '')
    {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3cWQP/

Comment: That is not elegant and you need to preventDefault to not submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Like this - give the select an ID and add this to the head. No other change needed to the html

```
var URLs = ["",
  "http://one.example.net",
  "http://two.example.net",
  "http://three.example.net",
  "http://four.example.net"
]
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("select1").onchange=function() {
    var URL = URLs[this.selectedIdex];
    if (URL) location=URL;       
  }
}
```

Or like this since you want a new tab - the browsers like to have a click open new windows

Give the form an ID and add `target="_blank"` to it too

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    var URL = URLs[this.selectedIdex];
    if (URL) {
      this.action=URL;      
      return true;
    }
    return false;// don't submit  
  }
}
```

To do this in php, submit the form which has target="_blank" and have the array on the server and do

```
header("location:".$urls[$_GET["select"]]);
```